# Help debugging 404 on apt-get install apache2

Tags: 16.04, apt, apache2

I'm trying to install an apache server on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04). I therefore ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Full traceback below. I also tried with --fix-missing as suggested by the traceback, but I still get 404s. I don't know how to debug this sort of issue. I have checked some of the URLs in a browsers and indeed they don't exist. So I think apt is looking in the wrong place. But that is odd since I just did apt-get update. Any help debugging the issue is appreciated.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 122 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,383 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,891 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 amd64 1.5.4-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
Err:2 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libaprutil1-ldap amd64 1.5.4-1build1
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
Err:3 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 liblua5.1-0 amd64 5.1.5-8ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
Err:4 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apache2-bin amd64 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
Err:5 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apache2-utils amd64 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
Ign:6 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 apache2-data all 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.14
Err:7 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apache2 amd64 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
Err:6 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 apache2-data all 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3_1.5.4-1build1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apr-util/libaprutil1-ldap_1.5.4-1build1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lua5.1/liblua5.1-0_5.1.5-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-bin_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-utils_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-data_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.14_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 197.155.77.2 works.
- http://za.archive.ubuntu.com works.
- http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/dists/xenial/ works.
- http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/dists/xenial-updates/ works.
- http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/dists/xenial/main/ works.

Either you are behind a proxy and are blocked from reaching them or their server is having maintenance or is unstable.

Comment: `http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` gives 404 Not Found on my system too. `http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/` gives folders `dists`, `indices`, `pool` and `project`.

Comment: Okay I'm on a university network so I'm probably behind a bunch of stuff. I'll retry when I'm home and update. Thank you.